# How to update a property on the viewmodel before calling a long running process?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have the following code:

```
Public Sub ExecuteMyCommand
   ShowProgressBar=True
   CallLongRunningProcess
   ShowProgressBar=False
End Sub
```

To get the progressbar in the UI to actually show before the long running process starts this code has to be rewritten to:

```
Public Async Sub ExecuteMyCommand
   ShowProgressBar=True
   Await Task.Run(Sub() CallLongRunningProcess)
   ShowProgressBar=False
End Sub
```

Now the problem:

In some methods the long running process involves creating WPF UserControls. These must be created on a STA thread. I have found how to do this, but then I get an InvalidOperationException because the user control is owned by non UI thread. So, I am looking for a way to update the ShowProgressBar property before calling the long running process on the UI thread (yeah, ugly, I know).

Comment: What do mean with 'So, I am looking for a way to update the ShowProgressBar property before calling the long running process on the UI thread' , it's just a bool , what do mean with update?

Comment: @Sybren The ShowProgressBar property is bound to ProgressBar.Visibility property in the view. Sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Dispatcher.Invoke? It keeps the tasks on the UI thread.
You'd have to move the `ShowProgressBar=False` into the delegate, of course.

```
Public Sub ExecuteMyCommand
    ShowProgressBar=True
    Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, New LongRunningProcessDelegate())
End Sub
```

I'd also separate UI modifying logic from the computing task, i.e. the task should call back into the UI thread when its done, and modification of UI elements would be left to the callback.

Comment: It worked well for me when I had to refresh the UI after an async db query finished, I wonder what's different in your case. I'm doing C# though. And the heavy computing was done by a background worker, of course. I'd never put a burden on the UI thread.

Comment: My apologies. Your solution does work for me. I must have done it slightly differently before.